# existing images in aws s3 linking to strapi collections without reupload

Tags: strapi, image-upload, aws-s3-client

We are in the process of revamping our site by replacing the CMS backend with Strapi. The existing site uses AWS S3 to store images, and we want to leverage these images in our new Strapi collections without re-uploading them.

Here’s our scenario:

We have images already uploaded to AWS S3.
We are creating new collections in Strapi to manage content.
We want to associate these existing images with entries in our Strapi collections when adding data through the Strapi API.
Could you please provide guidance on how to achieve this? Specifically, we are looking for the best practices and steps to set up Strapi to reference existing images in AWS S3 within our collections.

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!